# Faucet Handle Setscrew Loosens

Tags: faucet

Two lavatories in our house have American Standard Cadet centerset faucets, model 8115F.

[image]

Both show the same issue: the setscrews holding the handle to the cartridge loosen.

The setscrew and threads look undamaged, and feel correct: the hex key seats solidly in the screw, the screw threads nicely into the cartridge arm, and the screw tightens as I expect without any sense (in my hand) that the threads are damaged. Still, a month or two later, the handle is slightly loose. The pattern repeats. The faucets feel and operate correctly.

Is a  drop of removable threadlocker (Permatex Orange or Locktite Blue, for example) called for here? Something else? Trying to wrap the setscrew threads in dental floss would be challenging.

Any other ideas?

Comment: A dab of threadlocker does sound appropriate. You may want to contact American Standard to see what they suggest. Of course, if it's "you'll have to replace the whole thing", the response is "OK, I'll pick a different brand", then try to fix it yourself. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan <nods> Repair is much more attractive, as the undersink access in the master bath is just awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mysterfixit was right. Teflon tape on the setscrews has eliminated all the slop on one fixture, and almost all on the other. The status quo is now fine with me.

EDIT - five months later:

The handle became loose again. Disassembly revealed that the setscrew threads into a metal collar which is held by an interior part of the handle that's made of nylon; the nylon had fractured. (The handle in the identical guest bath fixture remains tight, I assume because it's used far less.)

It's a poor design. I'll get a replacement handle.

Answer (score 2):

Thread tape (PTFE) does add some friction initially, but recall that Teflon is often used as a *lubricant*. It'll probably let go before long.

I'd use removeable thread locker compound (blue Loctite) or just some white glue. It's not uncommon to see set screws from the factory with a dab pre-applied to one side.